# Who is this Daft Punk looking character?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I found this minifig on the ground in front of my house the other day.

Who is that and what set is it from?

A description of their features:

- Big, unruly black hair
- Golden “cyber goggles” that look like an amp level display
- Golden jacket that’s open and displays a silver body with abs
- USB cable and golden music note pendant around neck
- Silver hands
- Black legs
- Silver circuit designs on jacket and legs
- Crown-and-music-note logo on the back of jacket
- Backside of the head: goggles feature a connector

[image: minifig front view]
[image: minifig back view]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from [43107: HipHop Robot BeatBox](https://brickset.com/sets/43107-1/HipHop-Robot-BeatBox)

[image]

Comment: For context: which has only ever been on sale in 2021, which was a Covid year.

Comment: @Cœur why is that relevant?

Comment: @user253751 It tells you that this set is not currently available anymore and might be quite rare.